# PHP: Уменьшить картинку но получив хтмл-тег img и src на картинку-источник

Tags: php

Нужно уменьшить картинку на выходе средствами РНР но так чтобы в хтмл-коде получить тег img с src на саму картинку. Уменьшить нужно пропорционально указав только желаемую ширину. Если использовать например код

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$filename = 'test.jpg';
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = '360px';
$proportion = $width/$height;
$new_height = $new_width/$proportion;
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

то исходного хтмл-кода не получаю вообще (команда *Просмотр исходного кода* в Хроме вообще неактивна), только в панели просмотра кода вижу

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/test.php">
```

Нужно

1. чтобы сгенерировался исходный хтмл-код страницы с тегом
   `<img />`
2. чтобы атрибут `scr` в теге `img` вёл на саму
       картинку-источник т.е. на `http://localhost/test.jpg`, а не на
       файл `http://localhost/test.php`
3. чтобы скрипт работал с любыми
    возможными форматами картинок (jpg, png, gif) а не с указанным вручную например только с jpg

Функцию `imagecopyresampled()` привел только для примера, я с ней не знаком и если с ней достичь всех трех целей невозможно тогда как?

Comment: А почему бы вам не положить картинку на сервере сразу в уменьшенном виде, при желании большую картинку сохранить в какой нибудь другой папке. Иначе вам надо использовать mod_rewrite, что бы обращения к картинкам переписывал на стороне сервера в обращения к скрипту. А скрипт анализируя полученный url будет формировать картинку

Comment: `mod_rewrite` это какие то записи в файле .htaccess имеются в виду или что то другое, что именно?

Comment: Да, именно записи в .htaccess

Comment: А `положить картинку на сервере сразу в уменьшенном виде` имеется в виду во время загрузки оригинала? Или можно как то скопировать все большие картинки (если они уже все загружены) в отдельную папку для миниатюр, указав им желаемые размеры?

Comment: Надо сделать скрипт на подобии вашего, который будет изменять размер картинки и прогнать через него все имеющиеся картинки. Потом то же самое делать для всех вновь поступивших

Comment: Да, если можете напишите пример в ответе, но только как периодически прогонять УЖЕ загруженные (как уменьшать в момент загрузки новой картинки не надо, поскольку это Виртумарт, влезать в его модели и хелперы будет сложно)

Comment: На php никогда этого не делал. только bash скриптами, но там кучу библиотек в систему надо ставить

Comment: А у вас в вопросе готовый пример. заключите его в цикл по всем файлам в каталоге и пишите себе в другой каталог маленькие версии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается можно воспользоватся моим скриптом, только в `imagejpeg()` (или `imagepng/imagegif`) вторым параметром указать переменную. Тогда в той же папке создаются уменьшенные картинки. В общем нашел такое решение:

```
<?php
$arrayOfImages = array('png_test.png','jpg_test.jpg','gif_test.gif');

// или взять все картинки с папки
$arrayOfImages = array();
$dir = '/path/to/folder/';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $key => $file) {
    if($key == 0 || $key == 1) {
        unset($file);
    }
    if(strpos($file,'.jpg') !== false || strpos($file,'.png') !== false || strpos($file,'.gif') !== false) {
        if(strpos($file,'_360') === false) {
            $arrayOfImages[] = $file;
        }
    }
}

foreach($arrayOfImages as $imgFile) {
    $info = getimagesize($imgFile);
    $width = $info['0'];
    $height = $info['1'];
    $mime = $info['mime'];
    $new_width = '360px';
    $proportion = $width/$height;
    $new_height = $new_width/$proportion;
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $suffix = '_360';
    switch($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgFile);
            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            $ext = '.jpg';
            $parts = explode($ext, $imgFile);
            $dest = $parts[0].$suffix.$ext;
            imagejpeg($image_p, $dest, 100);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($imgFile);
            imagealphablending($image_p, false);
            imagesavealpha($image_p, true);
            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            $ext = '.png';
            $parts = explode($ext, $imgFile);
            $dest = $parts[0].$suffix.$ext;
            imagepng($image_p, $dest);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($imgFile);
            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            $ext = '.gif';
            $parts = explode($ext, $imgFile);
            $dest = $parts[0].$suffix.$ext;
            imagegif($image_p, $dest);
            break;
    } // end of switch

    echo '<img src="'.$dest.'" alt="" />';
} // end of foreach
?>
```

Вот бы кейсы как то упростить чтобы не дублировать одно и то же, не знаю как

Comment: Создать класс например

Comment: Но как, если в начале должна быть своя функция `imagecreate...` в зависимости от входного миме-типа. Разве что условия использовать

Comment: кейсы сделать методами и вызывать нужный метод в зависимости от типа файла self::myclass->{phg}

Comment: А можете fiddle где то накинуть?